# CPU usage when rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

So I'm rendering a scene using OPTIX and only my GPU (RTX 2070 Super). For some reason, when the time left on my render hits 0.04 seconds, my CPU usage hits 100% for a few seconds and then goes back down once the render finishes, no matter how I optimized the settings, this always happens. How can I make this not happen and why does it happen?

Comment: Compositor? Denoising probably

Comment: The compositor N-panel has some performance options including enabling OpenCL for gpu calculations.

Comment: which version of Blender?

Comment: If you are using a denoiser other than Optix, such as NLM this will happen. Also, writing a file in itself can need some CPU.